# Small issue when running Python code straight from VIM

Tags: python, vim

I want to be able to set up the hot key `\\` to be able to write and run python script from VIM without each time having to type in

```
:w
:! python3 file.py
```

What I have done so far is pasted the following into my vimrc file:

```
"{{{ The following is for sourcing command.vim whenever exists.
" Function to source only if the file command.vim exists
" https://devel.tech/snippets/n/vIIMz8vZ/load-vim-source-files-only-if-they-exist
"
function! SourceIfExists(file)
  if filereadable(expand(a:file))
    echom a:file . " is about to be sourced."
    exe 'source' a:file
  endif
endfunction
autocmd BufEnter * call SourceIfExists("command.vim")
" }}}
```

and then in the same directory that my python file is, I create a file named command.vim and paste the following inside that file:

```
noremap <leader><leader> :w <cr> :!python3 % &<cr>
```

Now this almost works perfectly except for the following issue. Suppose I want to run the following script, which I'll call file.py:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)
y = np.linspace(6, 10, 5)

print('{}\n{}'.format(x, y))
```

If I run this the standard way by using `:! python3 file.py` then the output is the following:

```
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
[ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But, if I use the `\\` method to run the same script, I get the following output:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
                                                          [ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
```

and you can see that the output of the script using `\\` is not formatted nicely like it is when using the standard command `:! python3 file.py`.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: [vi.se] is probably a better place to ask. It looks like it has to do with how `vim` processes the output of the command.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/38631/210

Answer (score 0):

What your mapping does:

```
:w
:!python3 % &
```

is different from what you do manually:

```
:w
:!python3 file.py
```

If you want the same outcome as the manual way, you will simply have to do the same thing:

```
nnoremap <leader><leader> :w<cr>:!python3 %<cr>
```

It is the unnecessary `&` that is causing your problem: it sends the command to the background, so Vim thinks it is finished and it takes back control of the terminal. But the background job still prints its output to the same terminal as Vim and you get a mess. Removing that `&` will fix your mapping.

---

By the way, the whole `command.vim` thing is a) useless, b) over-complicated, and b) a red herring. You should remove it from the question… and from your `vimrc`.

Comment: If I remove `command.vim`, where do I put `nnoremap <leader><leader> :w<cr>:!python3 %<cr>`?

Comment: Where it belongs, in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Comment: I do not have that on my computer? Also, I still ran into the same issue with the `command.vim` method when using you suggestion: `nnoremap <leader><leader> :w<cr>:!python3 %<cr>`

Comment: You are supposed to create that file.

Comment: Thank you. However this method introduces a new problem that wasn't there when I had the `command.vim` method. If I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` and do a `plt.show`, I now can not go back to my code until I close the plot that was created. With the `command.vim` method, I was able to keep the plot open and still edit my code.

Comment: See `:help :terminal` for a better approach to all this.

Comment: I gave you the solution to the specific problem described in your question. That plot problem is a separate problem which shows that your needs are not one-dimensional: what works for one script might not work for another script so either you make different commands for each case or you figure out *all* your requirements and try your hands at a more generic solution. Using the built-in `:terminal` might be a much better approach, here. And again, that `command.vim` business is a red herring.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Ill have to do some digging around to figure out the plot issues